# How to delete a specific line of a paragraph in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, text

I have a text variable of class `text` that shows something like this when it is returned:

```
"
This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 2.
This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4."
```

I want to be able to delete specific lines from the text, without affecting the rest of the variable:

For example: `delete {1, 3}` to get this result:

```
"This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4."
```

Comment: Graham Miln, @patrix, Technically the other question is the duplicate of this question because, 1. This one was asked before the other. 2. rubik's sphere edited the other question to a point that it's become a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @user3439894 I've merged the two questions now, which combines all existing answers. Feel free to clean up your answer :-)