# How to delete a specific line of a paragraph in AppleScript, while retaining the original format of the text?

Tags: macos, applescript, bug, text

I have a text variable of class `text` that shows something like this when it is returned:

```
"
This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 2.
This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4."
```

I want to be able to delete specific lines from the text, without affecting the rest of the variable.

For example: `delete {1, 3}` to get this result:

```
"This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4."
```

---

The method described in this answer has a serious bug:

[*"How to delete a specific line of a paragraph in AppleScript?"*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276240/how-to-delete-a-specific-line-of-a-paragraph-in-applescript/276261#276261)

The linked method to delete lines in a paragraph actually converts all linefeeds in the text variable to returns. In other words, it is impossible to run this code more than once on the same variable.

For example, the following code:

```
set varText to "
This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 2.
This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4."
set varText to do shell script "sed -e '1d;3d' <<< " & quoted form of varText
-- Employing the same method on the same variable:
set varText to do shell script "sed -e '1d;3d' <<< " & quoted form of varText
return varText
```

returns

`""`

Since this method only works correctly if the lines of the text variable are the product of a `linefeed` (as it should), the problem is ***not*** that this method fails to perceive a `return` as a new line (as I had originally claimed in this question). The problem is that this code introduces a `return` to the text variable in the first place.

---

Thus, I want a solution that will allow me to **run the same text variable through the solution more than once** in the same AppleScript.

In other words, I am looking for a method to remove a specific line from a paragraph that does not have this bug and does not insert a `return` anywhere in the text.

Comment: Regarding info in your **Edit:**: The `do shell script "sed ..."` _command_ when run in Terminal with that `varText` returns with `\n` (x0A) not `\r` (x0D) as it's supposed to. Even the compiled `do shell script "sed ..."` _command_ in Script Editor still has `\n` (x0A) not `\r` (x0D) however why it's being returned with `\r` (x0D) intend of the expected `\n` (x0A) is a mystery to me at the moment. I'm going to consider this an AppleScript bug since it not mirroring the expected behavior of the same when run in Terminal.  This is why I deleted my answer because I wasn't aware of the issue.

Comment: GrahamMiln Since now I've identified the bug with the original answer that led me to post the second question, is it possible to merge these two questions together? If not, can you just delete this question altogether, since @user3439894 has provided their updated answer on the second question?

Comment: I don't want to delete this question myself, because doing so will result in a strike against my SE account. (I understand that the act of deleting one's own question is penalized).

Comment: On your point about using `return`, I of course agree! In reality, I _don't_ use and _have never_ used `return` to concatenate multi-line strings! That's why I had to significantly edit the title and body of this question; my post contained several inaccurate statements. This post was first published _before_ I had picked up on the bug in your code, which (I eventually realized) explained where all the `returns` in my text variables were coming from! I had originally assumed that **_I_** was—somehow—responsible for the prevalence of the `return` characters, which, now I know, is not the case.

Comment: First of all it was not my code per se that had the bug! It's a bug in how the `do shell script` _command_ is processing what's returned from the _command line_, it's AppleScript that's not properly processing the output of the command(s) executed within the `do shell script` _command_! Your use of `return` as a multi-line string concatenation was a problem as `sed` saw the contents of the variable as one line and deleted it because it's expecting `x0A` not `x0D` line endings. Anyway my updated answer handles both the poor use of `return` over `linefeed` and the bug.

Comment: Yes, I obviously did not mean to imply that _you_ personally are responsible :). When I stated, _"bug in your code,"_ it was shorthand for, _"the AppleScript bug that manifested in the solution that you provided."_ You wrote, _"Your use of return as a multi-line string concatenation was a problem."_ As I said, I completely misunderstood the issue at hand (bc I failed to realize the AppleScript bug) when I provided that example of using `return` to concatenate in the original post.

Comment: I have not once in my entire life actually used `return` to concatenate; that example existed to highlight a problem that was not actually the problem.  Unrelated question... have you had a chance to corroborate my observation about Graham's answer?

Comment: Okay, I played with his code and it does look like it's not working as you want it to even when replacing all but the last `return` with `linefeed` or using the other method of setting the variable. I'll look more closely tomorrow as I'me done for the night. Anyway, my answer employs a bug fix and can handle `return` when used as a text class special string character constant and or what's returned from the `do shell script` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've deleted the original and first edit because you've edited your originally question to the point it's easier to write a new answer altogether.

Since your originally question showed the following line of *code*, as an example of how the variable may be set, I'm going to include it to say the following.

Whether the `varText` has been set by e.g.:

```
set varText to (return & "This is sentence 1." & return & "This is sentence 2." & return & "This is sentence 3." & return & "This is sentence 4.")
```

- In which `return` is `x0D` vs. the more proper use of `linefeed` (`x0A`) instead, in a case where the variable is *data* and not a disposable message.

Or:

```
set varText to "
This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 2.
This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4."
```

- In which each of these lines actually end with a `linefeed` (`x0A`) as it should be on a Mac.

The `do shell script` *command* has a **bug** as it converts `x0A` to `x0D` after what's returned from the *command line* having the expected `x0A` endings passed back. I confirmed this because if I use the following:

```
set varText to "
This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 2.
This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4."

set varText to do shell script "sed  -e '1d;3d' <<< " & quoted form of varText & " | tee $HOME/Desktop/outfile"
```

Then `outfile` contains `linefeed` (`x0A`) endings so the same is returned to `do shell script` but it then erroneously converts the `x0A` line endings to `x0D` endings which can then handled by the following:

So, to accommodate the **bug**, always insure the content of the variable passed and returned contains `x0A` line endings by using the following `handler` and example *code*.

The following assumes that `varText` has already been set by either of the methods described above.

```
on ensureLinesEndWith0A(varText)
    set varText to paragraphs of varText
    set oldTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
    set varText to varText as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTID
    return varText
end ensureLinesEndWith0A

set varText to ensureLinesEndWith0A(varText)
set varText to do shell script "sed  -e '1d;3d' <<< " & quoted form of varText
set varText to ensureLinesEndWith0A(varText)
```

You could then use the following again to delete more lines from `varText`:

```
set varText to ensureLinesEndWith0A(varText)
set varText to do shell script "sed  -e '1d;3d' <<< " & quoted form of varText
set varText to ensureLinesEndWith0A(varText)
```

The image below shows and example of calling the `do shell script " sed ..."` *command* twice.

[image: image of code example]

Comment: @rubik's sphere, Checkout the image I added to my answer.

Comment: I have tested your `text item delimiters to linefeed` workaround. I believe that it successfully corrects the pernicious little AppleScript bug that we've identified. I can now perform countless `do shell script "sed  -e...` operations on the same text variable within the same run of a script, and the specified lines are reliably deleted as intended. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
set varText to "
This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 2.
This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4."

set varText to do shell script "sed -e '1d;3d' <<< " & quoted form of varText
```

**Returns:**

```
"This is sentence 1.
This is sentence 3.
This is sentence 4."
```

---

**Update:** As a result of a discovery mentioned in the **Edit:** of [How to delete a specific line of a “return”-based paragraph in AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276450/how-to-delete-a-specific-line-of-a-return-based-paragraph-in-applescript), let me make the following statement:

**NOTE:** Unfortunately what's returned in this case has *carriage return* (x0D) *characters* instead of the expected *new line* (x0A) characters and in my opinion is a bug!

**It's a bug because:** The `do shell script "sed ..."` *command* when run in Terminal with that `varText` returns with `\n` (x0A) not `\r` (x0D) as it's supposed to. Even the compiled `do shell script "sed ..."` *command* in Script Editor still has `\n` (x0A) not `\r` (x0D) however why it's being returned with `\r` (x0D) intend of the expected `\n` (x0A) is a mystery to me at the moment and I'm going to consider this an AppleScript bug since it not mirroring the expected behavior of the same when run in Terminal.

So, to account for the *bug* in the results of the `do shell script "sed ..."` *command*, this is how I'd handle it. After the `do shell script "sed ..."` *command* use the following lines of *code*:

```
set newLine to "\n"
set varText to paragraphs of varText
set oldTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to newLine
set varText to varText as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTID
```

Now what's returned contains *new line* (x0A) *characters* as it should have to begin with if there wasn't this bug, not *carriage return* (x0D) *characters*.

---

Note: When compiled, the `set newLine to "\n"` line of *code* will show as below:

```
set newLine to "
"
```

Comment: If I am removing only one line, do you suggest that I include the semicolon? I tried it both ways (with and without the semicolon) and it seems to work fine either way, but I am just asking for your preference.

Comment: @rubik's sphere, The semi-colon is only needed as a separator when more then one range is specified, in this use case. Which line are you wanting to delete?

Comment: Did you see the last part of my new question? It is impossible to run this method twice on the same variable, which must mean that your line deletion method alters the new line (x0A) characters to something else (in the process of deleting a line).

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down this script into smaller pieces and then put it all together in one AppleScript.

This approach is written entirely in AppleScript and requires no external tools. Using external tools, like `perl` or `sed`, will likely result in much shorter solutions but you have mentioned in other questions wanting to learn AppleScript.

### 1. Split with Delimiters

You can use AppleScript's **delimiters** behaviour to [split a string](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24473). You can change the delimiter as desired to `return`, `linefeed`, or even characters like `=` :

```
 -- http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24473
 to split(someText, delimiter)
     set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delimiter
     set someText to someText's text items
     set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""} --> restore delimiters to default value
     return someText
 end split

 set myText to (return & "This is sentence 1." & return & "This is sentence 2." & return & "This is sentence 3." & return & "This is sentence 4.")
 set myLines to split(myText, return)
```

### 2. Filter List

With the returned list, you can [filter out the undesirable items](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24525) using a loop:

```
 -- http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24525
 set indexesToDelete to {1, 4}
 set cleanList to {}

 repeat with i from 1 to count myLines
     if i is not in indexesToDelete then set cleanList's end to myLines's item i
 end repeat
```

### 3. Combine the Items

The filtered list of sentences can be re-combined using another loop:

```
-- Combine the filtered list into a string
set myResult to ""
repeat with i from 1 to count cleanList
    if myResult is "" then
        set myResult to cleanList's item i
    else
        set myResult to myResult & return & cleanList's item i
    end if
end repeat
```

## Entirely AppleScript

Combining these snippets results in the following code:

```
-- Get the text to work with
set myText to (return & "This is sentence 1." & return & "This is sentence 2." & return & "This is sentence 3." & return & "This is sentence 4.")

-- Split the text into lines based on 'return' delimiter
set myLines to split(myText, return)

-- Filter out indexes 1 and 4 using a loop
set indexesToDelete to {1, 4}
set cleanList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count myLines
    if i is not in indexesToDelete then set cleanList's end to myLines's item i
end repeat

-- Combine the filtered list into a string
set myResult to ""
repeat with i from 1 to count cleanList
    if myResult is "" then
        set myResult to cleanList's item i
    else
        set myResult to myResult & return & cleanList's item i
    end if
end repeat

-- Final string
myResult

to split(someText, delimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delimiter
    set someText to someText's text items
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""} --> restore delimiters to default value
    return someText
end split
```

The script above could be reduced by combining the filter and re-combination loops. I have left these as separate tasks to better demonstrate their roles.

Comment: Your strategy also suffers from the exact same bug found in the original method provided by @user3439894 (the bug is described in the "Edit:" part of my post). I.e., if `myText` contains linefeeds instead of returns, and you use the line: `set myLines to split(myText, linefeed)`, your code will convert every linefeed that exists in the text to a return, making it impossible for the same text variable to successfully run through your method more than once. I was hoping for a solution that doesn't possess this problematic side effect; I want to delete lines from the same variable more than once.

Comment: @rubik's sphere, Graham Miln's answer does not suffer from the same bug as he's not using a `do shell script` _command_, which is where the bug is. He's using `return` just like you originally showed in the original version of this question! You should not use `return` to concatenate multi-line _strings_, you should use `linefeed` instead. As a matter of fact if you replaced all be the last `return` to `linefeed` in his answer it would work as expected by maintaining `x0A` line endings vs. the `x0D` which `return` does when used as a `text` class special string character constant.

Comment: @user3439894 You are right in that it is not, technically, the "same" bug. To be clear, Graham's method has a different bug, but one with the exact same effect as the bug in your `do shell script` method. This is the test: using linefeeds in the place of returns in Graham's answer, can you run a specific text variable through his method more than once in the same script with everything still working properly (e.g., by first deleting the second line of the paragraph and then deleting the third line, in two separate statements)?